# Filter reports by the interval between two dates

Tags: reporting, administration, joined-reports

My Opportunities have Start Date and Close Date. These are treaties. Between these dates the company makes a profit. I need to show in the report how much profit the company receives in a month and a year. But the contract can start (Start Date) in March and close (Close Date) in April. For example, I need to display exactly the profit, which turned out in April, discarding the days of profit in March. How can I do it?

My wrong decision (with this decision, unfortunately, I exclude the possibility of starting in the previous month or finishing in the next month):

[image]

Comment: Do you want opportunities to show in the report that has start date OR close date in the current month?

Comment: @tugce yes.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to **add** your filters by THIS MONTH first for Start & Close date then add a filter logic. To add filter logic you can click to the button next to filters. Here is the documentation for adding filter logic to the [reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_logic.htm&type=5). For your case it would be `1 AND (2 OR 3)` if you have your filters in this order; Record Type, Start Date, Close Date

Don't forget to add Close Date filter again because filter logic can be applied to the filters you added to the report, not the default ones.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works :)

Comment: 1 more question. Will I be able to count the number of days this month, based on these filters? How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by counting the days?